# Replacing "echo -e" with Heredoc

Tags: shell, jenkins, gradle-properties

My jenkinsfile contains a really long one-line shell command to create gradle.properties. For better readability I replaced it with Heredoc. It does fail now though and I am unsure why. Can you spot the error?

One-liner that does not fail is in this format:

```bash
sh("echo -e \"\nSOME_KEY=${VARIABLE_1}\nANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_2}\nYET_ANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_3}\" >> gradle.properties")
```

Failing Heredoc format:

```bash
sh("""cat << EOF >> gradle.properties
SOME_KEY=${VARIABLE_1}
ANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_2}
YET_ANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_3}
EOF""")
```

Comment: What's with all the indentation in your heredoc?

Comment: My mistake. This happened when pasting and formatting on stackoverflow.

Comment: @yelinek Is your multiline string correct? I'm not familiar with multiline strings in Jenkinsfiles specifically, but I'm assuming that the one you put will evaluate to `"cat << EOF >> gradle.propertiesSOME_KEY=${VARIABLE_1}ANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_2}YET_ANOTHER_KEY=${VARIABLE_3}EOF"`. Try putting a space at the beginning of each line of the multiline string.

Comment: Alternatively you may need to insert EOL characters.

Comment: @shellter tripple `"` is a multiline string in jenkinsfile